# Ansible: In a playbook, filter a role by tag(s) without passing at the command-line

Tags: ansible

In Ansible 1.7, I can use --tags from the command-line to only run a subset of that playbooks tasks.

But I'm wanting to bake into my playbook to run a set of roles with only tasks that match tags. That is, I don't want to have to pass this in via the command-line since it will be the same every time.

At first I thought it was this command, but this does the opposite: tagging tasks with these tags instead of filtering them out based on this.

```
roles:
  - { role: webserver, port: 5000, tags: [ 'web', 'foo' ] }
```

I can imagine implementing this using conditionals but tags would be a much more elegant way of achieving this.

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm wanting to do this is to run all the package install tasks across multiple roles so I can have a create an AMI that caches all updates/upgrades/installs. Then I can use this as my base AMI. Have the script working and will just specify via command-line for now

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You only have the following options with the current version of Ansible:

1. Specify the tags on the command line
2. Use a variable instead of a tag to conditionally run tasks
3. Split your webserver role into multiple roles and use role dependencies for the common tasks

This feature request [has come up on the mailing list a few times](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Ansible-project/hSR8CVcxHwE/tgv4YcVY3jIJ) and I haven't seen any indication from the dev team that it will be added as a new feature.

Comment: Surprised more people aren't clamoring for this! Thanks for the answer on this

Comment: This summarized the options very well. In my case, neither of them were too appealing, but I had to go with a bash script chaining a bunch of `ansible-playbook` commands together (option #1) to make it work.

Comment: agreed, I would much rather define tags in my playbook, instead of having to explicitly set them on the commandline. I'll have to use variables instead, but conditionally running tasks seems to be way more cumbersome that it ought to be

Answer (score 0):

The use of conditionals can meet your needs.

You can see more information in my answer to another person's similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/675076/275995).