# Ansible: Playback with same defaults/magic as a role's main.yml

Tags: deployment, ansible, devops

I often have a need for "custom playbooks" that do specific tasks, but still  within one role, e.g. for a database backup task, I'd want it to be in roles/databases/backup.yml. A custom task like this would enjoy the same ["magic"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) that main.yml enjoys (automatically reading role variables and so on).

The only workaround for this is relying on tags inside main.yml, but that's cumbersome - requires creating an "obstacle course" of tags just to ensure certain tasks are run, and specifying the tag on command-line (since a play cannot run a tag-filtered list of other plays).

I end up having to do everything manually and explicitly in a custom file.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explicitly state your question?  As I understand it, you want a custom playbook within in a role--so why not create a separate tasks file in the role and include it (with a 'when: ..')?

Comment: All tasks in main.yml are run by default, so using "when" would require adding "when" tags to every task in order to exclude it. e.g. if I have one "backup" task among 10 total tasks, I'd have to mark the other 9 as "when not backup" to prevent them from running. And if I had a second task "restore", I'd have to add "when not restore" to the 9 tasks that are not restore. So I don't think it's really practical to use the main role file to specify custom tasks. And yet, it's the only apparent way to get those nice defaults.

Comment: You can't do something in your main.yml: include: 'tasks/backup.yml' when: backup == 'yes'  ... and then in your backup.yml have your backup related tasks? That's how I'd do it.You could then pass in the backup variable on the command line.

Comment: Yes, thinking further, this is really the best practice at the moment, if less than optimal. Left an answer here elaborating.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking further, the confusion is because I'm trying to work around two limitations of Ansible: (a) as mentioned, [there's no way for a task to run a list of tagged tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25675696/18706); (b) [there's no such thing (yet) as "explicit" tags](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11045), ie tags that disable a task unless the tag is explicitly invoked. This means there's no simple way to run a particular subset of special/exceptional tasks within a playbook.

I was trying to work around this restriction by making a separate playbook. However, that would end up copying a bunch of logic from the main role playbook anyway.

The best approach for now is the workaround [others have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28789968/18706), which is to rely on variables as a workaround for "whitelisting" certain tasks. Then make a wrapper script which declares those variables and may also use skip-tags to eliminate unnecessary/slow tasks.